# Laravel 4: Get ID of last attached record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In Laravel 4, how can I retrieve the ID of the last inserted pivot record?

My models are defined like this:

```
class Action extends Eloquent
{
    public function people()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Person')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('mailing_data');
    }
}

class Person extends Eloquent {
    public function actions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Action')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

and I'd like to get the ID of the record inserted through
`$action->people()->attach($person_id);`

Is there a way without using `mysql_insert_id`? I would prefer an Eloquent way.

I am using Laravel 4, not 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ideally use `mysqli_insert_id` not the deprecated `mysql_insert_id`, although you will need to ensure you use the same connection.

The simplest and safest way to solve your problem in an 'Eloquent' way is to simply use the facts that you already know (the `$person_id` and the thing you're attaching people to) to find the pivot record ID through a query.

EDIT: Or, if the `id` is important, consider not using pivot tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of the second fact, but I thought, as for instance `$person->save()` sets the generated id, there is a similar way for `attach()`

Comment: It's possible there is a better way. But there aren't many use cases for pivot table IDs, so retrieving it easily isn't important, thus it doesn't surprise me that it isn't a way in Eloquent (as far as we can find) or probably most ORMs. The records are always going to be unique, so you'd never need to distinguish between otherwise identical records. I can't imagine when you would know the pivot table record ID but not the two connecting IDs.

There was an answer here that was unsafe; it suggested you just pick up the MAX id. My way may not be elegant but it is safe and understandable.

Comment: I know the two connecting IDs. For me, a Person can have the same Action multiple times, so `n` records with the `person_id`-`action_id` combination exist. I have additional data in this pivot table that I need to access through a mailing queue, so I'm not sure if i could rely on the MAX id

Comment: Ah. You're attaching people to actions. I'd design this differently - what you have as Action I'd have as ActionType, and I'd just have a simple table of PersonActions with the relevant IDs, dates and additional data. So you'd end up with the ID because you'd be doing `$personAction->save()` like you're used to.